# Strict transform becomes unmovable after enough blow ups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$. We say that an irreducible hypersurface $V\subseteq M$ is unmovable if $V$ is there is no other effective divisor numerically equivalent to $V$.

Consider now an infinite sequence
$$ \dots \to M_{i+1}\to M_i\to \dots\to M_0=M$$
where $M_{i+1}\to M_i$ is the blow up of $M_i$ along a smooth subvariety $Z_i\subseteq M_i$. Now fix an hypersurface $V=V_0\in M$, and let $V_i\subseteq M_i$ be the proper transform. Suppose that for an infinite number of indexes $i$ we have that $Z_i$ is contained in $V_i$ and it has codimension $1$ in $V_i$, i.e. codimension $2$ in $M_i$.

If for some $i$ it happens that $V_i$ is unmovable, then for $j\ge i$ we have that $V_j$ is unmovable too, since proper pushforward respects numerical equivalence.

**Question 1:** is it always true that $V_i$ is unmovable for $i$ big enough?

**Question 2:** if the answer to question 1 is yes, can we do this uniformly in the degree of $V$? More precisely, suppose that $\{V_l\}_l$ is a possibly infinite set of hypersurfaces of $M$ each of degree at most $d$ with respect to some ample divisor. For every $l$ and $i$, let $\phi_l(i)$ the number of indexes $j=0,\dots,i$ such that $Z_i\subseteq V_{l,i}$ and it has codimension $1$ in $V_{l,i}$. Is it true that there exists a number $N$ such that $V_{l,i}$ is unmovable for every $i$ such that $\phi_l(i)>N$?

If $M$ is a surface, these are easily seen to be true by looking at the self intersection: in fact, the self intersection of a curve decreases each time we blow up one of its points, hence at some point it becomes negative, and a curve with negative self intersection is clearly unmovable.

This moreover is true uniformly in the degree, since if we have a set of curves  with bounded degree with respect to some ample divisor then they have bounded self intersection, too. One easy way of seeing this is that, since the Neron-Severi group is finitely generated and the effective cone is sharp, asking bounded degree with respect to some ample divisor imposes that there is a finite number of numerical equivalence classes.

I tried to generalize this argument in higher dimension, but the increased complexity keeps pushing me back.